# Newtonsoft.JSON's ContractResolver conflict with custom converter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I have this sample hierarchical data:

```
{
  "Name": "Car 1",
  "AvailableColors": [
    "Red",
    "Green"
  ],
  "RelatedItems": {
    "Brand": {
      "Name": "Brand 1",
      "RelatedItems": {
        "ImportingCompanies": [
          {
            "Name": "Company 1",
            "RelatedItems": {
              "CeoName": "CEO 1"
            }
          },
          {
            "Name": "Company 2",
            "RelatedItems": {
              "CeoName": "CEO 2"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically what I need is to copy all properties of any `RelatedItems` to its parent object. The result should become:

```
{
  "Name": "Car 1",
  "AvailableColors": [
    "Red",
    "Green"
  ],
  "Brand": {
    "Name": "Brand 1",
    "ImportingCompanies": [
      {
        "Name": "Company 1",
        "CeoName": "CEO 1"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Company 2",
        "CeoName": "CEO 2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm using ASP.NET Core and I have configured my startup this way:

```
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new RelatedItemsFlattenerJsonConverter());
});
```

and this is the code I've written for `RelatedItemsFlattenerJsonConverter`:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    JToken token = JToken.FromObject(value);
    if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        var array = (JArray)token;
        foreach (var item in token)
        {
            FlattenRelatedItems(item);
        }
    }
    else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        var @object = (JObject)token;
        FlattenRelatedItems(@object);
    }
    token.WriteTo(writer);
    stopwatch.Stop();
}

private void FlattenRelatedItems(JToken token)
{
    if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        var array = (JArray)token;
        foreach (var item in token)
        {
            FlattenRelatedItems(item);
        }
    }
    else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        var @object = (JObject)token;
        var relatedItemsProperty = @object.Properties().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name.ToLower() == "RelatedItems".ToLower());
        if (relatedItemsProperty.IsNotNull())
        {
            var relatedItems = @object[relatedItemsProperty.Name];
            @object.Remove(relatedItemsProperty.Name);
            var keys = ((JObject)relatedItems).Properties().Select(i => i.Name).ToList();
            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                @object.Add(key, relatedItems[key]);
            }
        }
        var properties = @object.Properties().ToList();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            FlattenRelatedItems(@object[property.Name]);
        }
    }
}
```

It works like a charm. However, when I add the custom `RelatedItemsFlattenerJsonConverter`, my API response's casing would become **PascalCase**d. And when I don't add it, the `ContractResolver` is respected and my API response is **camelCase**d. What should I do to both have the custom converter, and **camelCase** for the API?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `JToken.FromObject(value)` inside `WriteJson`, you are not passing it the serializer, so it does not know about the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` (or any other settings) you have configured.  `JToken.FromObject()` uses a new serializer instance internally by default.

However, in this case, if you pass in the serializer as is, you may run into a self-referencing loop, as the converter attempts to call itself.  What you need to do is create your own instance of `JsonSerializer` inside `WriteJson` and then copy the resolver reference (and any other important settings you want to keep, excluding the converter, of course) from the serializer that was passed to `WriteJson`.  Then pass that new serializer to `JToken.FromObject()`.

In other words, change this line:

```
JToken token = JToken.FromObject(value);
```

To this:

```
var innerSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
innerSerializer.ContractResolver = serializer.ContractResolver;
// if any other settings from the outer serializer are needed, copy them here
JToken token = JToken.FromObject(value, innerSerializer);
```